# What are the situations where taking Smite/Teleport top is appropriate?

Tags: league-of-legends

As Smite/Teleport top is being increasingly popular, I want to know what situations it can be used effectively in.

Answer (score 1):

The advantages of smite/teleport is that you have the ability to farm extra jungle creeps. (Golems for purple side, Frog for blue side). You also have the ability to roam around the map (One of the most important things about teleport is teleporting for dragon fights/bottom lane for kills and to set up dragon fights). Note that it is situational as normally smite/teleport is used at the highest level of play with teams supporting them. This is more difficult to succeed with at lower levels when teams are not as coordinated and flash is important to help survive from the enemy top laner/jungler.